# List Disk location of shares on server

Tags: command-line, network-shares, shared-folders

using `cmd prompt`, how can I get the **location of a share**?  I know the name of the share, but when I remote onto the box, I can't see where the share location is.

`net view` shows me the names, but not the locations.

Comment: I did search, but couldn't find anything obvious! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the net share command instead, ie simply:

```
net share
```

It will show you the 'resource' associated with the share which in your case should be the location on the disk.